# Ansible hosts' inventory yml doesn't support repeated ip with_items

Tags: ansible, yaml

The following:

```
  store_controller:
    hosts:
      SERVER:
        ansible_host: "{{ STORE_CTL }}"
        mgmt_ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
  global_mgmt:
    hosts:
      SERVER:
        ansible_host: "{{ NOMAD_SERVER }}"
        mgmt_ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
  node_exporter: ##if comment the part from here to end, it's ok####
    hosts:
      "{{ item }}":
        ansible_host: "{{ item }}"
        mgmt_ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    with_items:
      - "172.7.7.1"
      - "172.7.7.9"
      - "172.7.7.12"
```

But Ansible doesn't let me use 'with_items' here. It seems that ansible does not support iterator over hosts.

How can I define the hosts array in group node_exporter for my three IPs ?

Comment: I just want to define a few similar host in my .yml file. Each of them has a var 'mgmt_ip' that is equal to 'ansible_host'.

Comment: I already used 'ansible_host' before this part in the same .yml file like here(it's ok if no this part).

Comment: I found that if I remove ansible_host: "{{ item }}" from node_exporter， it will be ok....

Comment: Although I yet not know exactly why, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to define is this:

```
node_exporter:
  hosts:
    172.7.7.1:
    172.7.7.9:
    172.7.7.12:
  vars: 
    mgmt_ip: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

---

**Explanation**:

`mgmt_ip` defines only a template (string value) which will be resolved at the time it is used.

For each target machine `inventory_hostname` (thus `mgmt_ip`) will resolve to the IP address of currently executing host.

Using `ansible_host` to assign the same value as the inventory host name is an empty action, so you don't need that at all.

<sup>I don't think it brings any value/clarity to the code, but since you commented it was working for you, that's the way to achieve it with multiple hosts. All you achieve is creating an alias `mgmt_ip` to `inventory_hostname`.</sup>

---

**Regarding the premise of the question**:

`with_items:` for YAML is a dictionary key name (string value). It is Ansible that might or might not make use of it.

It makes use of it when it is specified in a task (there it has a semantic meaning).

Otherwise it either ignores it (never uses this key), or reports an error.

Answer (score -1):

Looking quickly at your code, you have an indentation problem.
Try to add 2 spaces before "{{item}}:"